# im getting the red everywhare Tap Activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

Im getting problem on the extends TapActivity !! it seems like i dont have such thing in the library 
and when i change it to extends Activity it all goes right exept
 getTapHost(); i don't know whats the problem its really annoying !!

```
        package com.example.eateqadat;

import android.app.TapActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class main extends TapActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Resources ressources = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTapHost(); 

        // Android tab
        Intent intentabout = new Intent().setClass(main.this, about.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecabout = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("عن البرنامج")
          .setContent(intentabout);




}
}
```

Comment: well now i really know that im so stupid

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just made a mistake with the spells here.

Make sure they are changed to `TabActivity` and `getTabHost()` ..